# Question about BSD license

Tags: zend-framework, licensing, freebsd

The zend framework is in BSD

if i make a leet product on zend can i sell it to ppl ?

Comment: I hope your programming is more sophisticated than your English.

Comment: What is `ppl` in above question?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because **it is about licensing or legal issues**, not programming or software development. [See here](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/274964/1402846) for details, and the [help/on-topic] for more.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes you can sell a product that uses components that use BSD -- maybe you'll have to say a word about those, but it will not prevent you from using them.

BSD Licenses are very permissive -- and allow proprietary use.

For more informations, you can take a look at :

- [BSD licenses](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BSD_licenses)
- [Zend Framework's licence](http://framework.zend.com/license) -- well, it's just a New BSD License, but states *(quoting)* :

  Redistribution and use in source and binary forms, with or without modification,
  are permitted provided that the following conditions are met:

  - Redistributions of source code must retain the above copyright notice,
    this list of conditions and the following disclaimer.
  - Redistributions in binary form must reproduce the above copyright notice,
    this list of conditions and the following disclaimer in the documentation
    and/or other materials provided with the distribution.
  - Neither the name of Zend Technologies USA, Inc. nor the names of its
    contributors may be used to endorse or promote products derived from this
    software without specific prior written permission.

As long as you respect this license -- i.e. include that copyright notice in the distributed source-code, that should be OK.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you may. See the license here:

http://framework.zend.com/license